# How to select rows in a dataframe based on an "or" operator of values of a column

Tags: python, dataframe, operators

Say I have a dataframe `df` which contains the variable `'Age'`.

I know if I want to select rows with `'Age' >= 25` and `'Age' <= 35` then I can use:

```
df1 = df[(df['Age']>=25) & (df['Age']<=35)]
```

What if I want to select rows with `'Age' <= 10` or `'Age' >= 40`. Is there an equivalent `or` sign just like how `and` sign is `&`? I have tried the code below and it doesn't work:

```
df1 = df[(df['Age']<=10) or (df['Age']>=40)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OR operators which is | (pipe). From the pandas docs.

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These must be grouped by using parentheses.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

This worked for me

```
df1 = df[(df['Age']<=10) | (df['Age']>=40)]
```

Comment: That's great! Many thanks for your swift reply and help